# Exercise 17.21 of Knuth’s TeXbook: a (known) error?

Tags: tex-core, texbook.tex

Exercise 17.21 of *The TeXbook* asks a question concerning `\delcode`:

> Appendix B defines `\delcode‘<` so that there is a shorthand notation for angle
>   brackets.  Why do you think Appendix B doesn’t go further and define `\delcode‘{`?

(quotation from that source).  The first sentence of the answer reads:

> If `\delcode‘{` were set to some nonnegative delimiter code,
>   you would get no error message when you wrote something like ‘`\left{`’.

But this is not true, at least as long as `{` retains its usual `\catcode`.  Indeed, the syntax rules in Chapter 26 explain that `\left` must be followed by a `<delim>`, which may be either

- `<filler>\delimiter<27-bit number>`,
- `<filler><letter>`, or
- `<filler><otherchar>`.

Now, leaving the first alternative alone, `<letter>` and `<otherchar>` are described informally in Chapter 24, more precisely on page 283 after the syntax for `<horizontal command>`, as being “explicit or implicit character tokens of categories 11 and 12” (respectively): thus, certainly not a `{` of category 1.  Actually, if you try the plain TeX code

```
\delcode`{="266308
\delcode`}="267309

Text before.
$$f(x)=\left{x+1\over x-1\right}+x$$
Text after.

\bye
```

you do get error messages (and the situation doesn’t change with LaTeX either).

I was reflecting about this inconsistency, which, as you can understand, threw me in bewilderment, all the more so in that the 2014 version of the *The TeXbook* reproduces the same wording I quoted above.  What should I think?  An incorrect statement that has incredibly slipped through all revisions and bug reports made so far?  A minor, unimportant, and well known issue that the Author decided to ignore?  Searching on Google for “TeXbook exercise 17.21” or on this site for “17.21” didn’t lead to anything. Please help.

**Addition**

Some comments suggest that I should not be asking this question at all.  But please understand that we are speaking, here, of a *conceptual* error that would have remained hidden for more than thirty years.  It seems to me that, if I were correct, the whole sense of Exercise 17.21 would be in doubt.

The answer I am expecting to get is one of the following:

1. No, it is *not* an error in *The TeXbook*: it’s *you* who are in error, because…
2. Yes, strictly speaking it *is* an error, but it is well known and has been ignored (and therefore, it has not been corrected) because…
3. Yes, it is an error and I had never heard of it before (and I am pretty sure of what I’m saying).

**Second addition**

I also intended to mention, but I forgot to do so, the remark made on p. 345, line -13, which is even more curious: it seems indeed that Knuth had in mind `{` characters of category 12.

**Third Addition**

Regarding the comment made on line 131 of `plain.tex`, mentioned by Arthur Reutenauer, that reads

```
% N.B. { and } should NOT get delcodes; otherwise parameter grouping fails!
```

the following sample code

```
%&plain
\delcode`{="266308
\delcode`}="267309

\def\test#1{This is the argument: ``#1''.}
\def\mathtest#1{#1^{2}}

Text before, including a test. \test{My argument}
$$f(x)=\left\{\mathtest{x}+1\over \mathtest{x}-1\right\}+x$$
Text after.

\bye
```

confirms that the function of parameter-delimiting of braces of category 1 and 2 is not affected when those character do get `\delcode`s (not even in math mode).

Comment: What kind of help do you need? You can easily send email to Barbara Beeton who will forward to the person in charge of these matters.

Comment: Note that ``\delcode`{="266308 \delcode`}="267309 $\left\Ucharcat`{ 12 \right\Ucharcat`} 12$`` works with the current XeTeX. `:-)`

Comment: @egreg: The help I need is about being absolutely sure this has never being reported before.  BTW, is Barbara Beeton still in charrge for collecting bugs about the TeXbook.

Comment: @egreg: Obviously, a category 12 `{` will work fine: it is an instance of `<otherchar>`! (:-)

Comment: Whether it has reported or not, you can send a bug report at `karl AT freefriends DOT org` (as suggested at http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/abcde.html).

Comment: Three is true. Of course, this is bug in TeXbook, no in TeX.

Comment: @wipet would you write an answer? (Nice to see you around, by the way).

Comment: +1 I don't know how many times I've read that and thought "that sounds strange what does he mean there" but never thought to make a test, I guess you are right and it's an error in the book!

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti I think your second addition is correct: Knuth simply wrote these remarks with a `{` of category 12 in mind.  That’s what you can read between the lines in the relevant place of plain.tex too (“N.B. { and } should NOT get delcodes; otherwise parameter grouping fails!”).  To know why, well, you’ll have to ask him :-)  If he remember ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lacking any evidence of the contrary, and in view of the comments that have been posted, I’ll assume that this is a genuine error that has somehow escaped close scrutiny until now, and I’ll proceed with the bug report.  Unfortunately, I cannot think of any correction I could suggest: I repeat that, in my humble opinion, the whole exercise loses its sense.

Comment: I think this contribution is part of the answer to exercise 27.5 ;-)

Comment: It's qurious if a test case can be devised where `{` has catcode 12. Did you try it? Will `\left{` produce errors then? (suppose that Appendix B is not to be concerned)

Comment: What response did you get for your bug report?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko: I’ve seen your comment just now.  The bug report has been “queued” for examination by Knuth: we must wait until his next review cycle, in… 2019, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @GuM: Where can I find out what Kuth has said in his review cycle?