# making \@namedef optionally global

Tags: scoping

I'd like to implement a `global` option on a package that I maintain, as per Mats's suggestion ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310666/mixing-sepfootnotes-endnotes-and-subfiles-and-declaring-notecontents-within-sub/319140?noredirect=1#comment781180_319140)). The package is `sepfootnotes`, and the suggested modification will allow footnotes' content definitions optionally to take global scope. This will make `sepfootnotes` compatible with the `subfiles` package.

So, the basic idea is to put a macro before `\@namedef`, say `\sep@scope`, and then let users define this macro either as `\global` or as something else to keep it local.

My question is: what should this something else be? What is the **safest** default expansion for this macro: `\relax`?

#### sepfootnotes.sty (beta, minimal)

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{sepfootnotes}[2016/07/17 v0.3c Footnotes in separate file]

\DeclareOption{global}{\sep@opt@globaltrue}
\newif\ifsep@opt@global
\ProcessOptions

\newcommand\sep@scope{\relax}
\ifsep@opt@global
 \renewcommand\sep@scope{\global}
\fi

\newcommand\sep@namedef[2]{\sep@scope\@namedef{prefix#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\sep@nameuse[1]{\@nameuse{prefix#1}}

\newcommand\sepfootnotecontent{\sep@namedef}
\newcommand\sepfootnote{\sep@nameuse}

\endinput
```

#### doc.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[global]{sepfootnotes}[2016/07/17 v0.3c]

\begin{document}

\begingroup
 \sepfootnotecontent{key}{content}
\endgroup

my \sepfootnote{key}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does it need to expand to anything?

Comment: I don't know. You mean, does `\sep@scope` need to expand to anything? Or the expansion of `\sep@scope` itself?

Comment: I would probably go with `\let\sep@scope\global` or `\let\sep@scope\empty`. If the choice for the latter is `\relax`, is it more than `{}`, since it's also not expandable.

Comment: The only thing I’d really be concerned about is that someone might want to use other prefixes as well.  Now, according to the syntax rules of p. 275, `\long\relax\def\test{A test}`, say, shouldn’t be legal, which suggests that `\let\sep@scope\@empty` is the right thing to do; nevertheless, I’ve tried the above input with both TeXLive’s `pdftex` and with the TeX program incorporated in OzTeX (`This is TeX, Version 3.14159`), and both accepted it.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti I believe that it should always be `\long`, because a footnote can consist of more than one paragraph.

Comment: `\long\relax\def` has always worked but I can't actually justify it via the syntax production in the texbook, maybe a documentation bug?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Indeed, module 1211 calls “⟨ Get the next non-blank non-relax non-call token 404 ⟩”.  Yes, I’d regard this as a (tiny) documentation bug.

Comment: report it to DEK via Karl and see if you get one of the famous virtual cheques:-)

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti : in the actual package, users are allowed to choose whatever prefix they want. (It defaults to `sepfoot`.) Users may even use multiple prefixes and then have multiple, independent footnote series in the same document.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I already have [this bug report](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/252230) pending, I’d better not add another one, lest Knuth think I want to become virtually rich at his virtual expense! (:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The suggested code is Ok, although a better default would probably be

```
\newcommand\sep@scope{}
```

but it introduces four csnames that are not really needed (`\ifsep@opt@global`, `\sep@opt@globaltrue`, `\sep@opt@globalfalse`, `\sep@scope`

an alternative scheme would be

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{sepfootnotes}[2016/07/17 v0.3c Footnotes in separate file]

\newcommand\sep@namedef[2]{\@namedef{prefix#1}{#2}}
\DeclareOption{global}{\renewcommand\sep@namedef[2]{\global\@namedef{prefix#1}{#2}}}
\ProcessOptions


\newcommand\sep@nameuse[1]{\@nameuse{prefix#1}}

\newcommand\sepfootnotecontent{\sep@namedef}
\newcommand\sepfootnote{\sep@nameuse}

\endinput
```

Comment: I will try to adapt your scheme to the actual `\sep@namedef`, as it actually expands to something much longer than that. I will drop `\sep@scope`, which is good, but keep `\ifsep@opt@global` and then modify the relevant line of `\sep@namedef` to `\ifsep@opt@global \global \@namedef {...}\else \@namedef{...}\fi`

Comment: Hi David and Eduardo. Trying to implement this, I would need some handholding. Is this accomplished by (1) moving up `\newcommand\sep@namereplace  [3] {\@namedef{sepfootnotes@text@#1@#2}{#3}}` to the top, (2) `\renewcommand` that in the `\DeclareOption` part and finally (3) replace `\@namedef{sepfootnotes@text@#1@#2}{#3}` in `\sep@namedef` with `\sep@namereplace{#1}{#2}{#3}`? Or am I missing the/a point?

Comment: The order in which macros are defined doesn't matter until they are used. There must be counterexamples but I think this is safe to say about my package. (By the way, I decided merely to prepend `\ifsep@opt@global\global\fi` to occurrences of `\@namedef`)